# QuickFIX what are StartTime and EndTime settings supposed to do?

Tags: quickfix, fix-protocol

I'm trying to understand the StartTime and EndTime setting in the QuickFIX config file. I'm using QuickFIX .Net to implement a buy side FIX client, set as a initiator.

By default , both StartTime and EndTime set to 00:00:00

So every time my program run (it calls initiator.start()) , it auto send Logon message to server. No problem.

And then I play around the StartTime and EndTime setting. Not much details about it in the QuickFIX doc. I suppose when I run the program , and application will send Logon message at StartTime, and Logout at EndTime isn't it?

So I set the StartTime and EndTime to say 10:00 and 11:00

I started the program at 09:50, the program just created the session and doesn't send Logon message. Make sense. Then at 10:00, nothing happened...

Next trial I started the program at 10:50, the program created the session and logon as usual. Than at 11:00 , nothing happened again. I suppose it will auto logout...

So my question is how are StartTime and EndTime supposed to affect my program?

Comment: Did you specify your times in UTC?  When you say it doesn't send Logon, how are you checking that?  Have you checked for anomalies in your event/message logs?

Comment: Yes , I checked the event and message log. I set the UseLocalTime=Y, so I used local time in StartTime and EndTime

Comment: Alright, look like the UseLocalTime setting is not working. I used UTC and it work now. Thanks all

Comment: Don't use LocalTime. Use UTC time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [the docs](http://www.quickfixengine.org/quickfix/doc/html/configuration.html):

- **ID:** StartTime

  - **Description:** Time of day that this FIX session becomes activated
  - **Valid Values:** time in the format of HH:MM:SS, time is represented in UTC
- **ID:** EndTime

  - **Description:** Time of day that this FIX session becomes deactivated
  - **Valid Values:** time in the format of HH:MM:SS, time is represented in UTC

So, yes, you have it roughly right.  At `StartTime`, your app will attempt to log on.  At `EndTime`, it will logoff.  Between those times, it will continually try to reconnect.

*Not mentioned* is that this time window determines when your sequence numbers will reset.  At `StartTime`, the engine will reset sequence numbers back to 0. For this reason, it's vitally important that your StartTime/EndTime be in sync with your counterparty.

Comment: AFAICT sequence numbers are reset by using `ResetOnLogon`, `ResetOnLogout`, `ResetOnDisconnect` and `ForceResync` configuration options (with default values of No). Your last sentence seems to suggest otherwise.

Comment: We're both right.  Some counterparties want seqnums to be reset on every single reconnect, regardless of session start/end times.  These settings enable such behavior.  (I don't honestly know why there is a need for 3 separate `ResetOnX` settings; seems to me like `ResetOnLogon` is enough.)

Comment: Here is my config

[DEFAULT]
ConnectionType=initiator
ReconnectInterval=60
FileStorePath=store
FileLogPath=log
UseLocalTime=Y
StartTime=09:33:00
EndTime=09:40:00
UseDataDictionary=Y
DataDictionary=C:/quickfix/spec/FIX42.xml
HttpAcceptPort=9911

This was 09:32 local time (UTC +8) here I started the program, it have following in log

20160113-01:32:15.549 : Created session

So now the time passed 09:35, nothing happened, nothing in log.

Comment: Alright, look like the UseLocalTime setting is not working. I used UTC and it work now. Thanks all

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but unless you set either `ResetOnLogon` or `ResetOnLogout` to `Y`, the QuickFIX engine will not reset the sequence number no matter what the counterparty does.

Comment: @TT QuickFIX always resets sequence numbers for a new session. That's what defines it being a new session

Answer (score 2):

Found out the old QuickFix/n library have bug on the UseLocalTime setting. I rebuilt my program with the latest v1.5 it works as expected.